# How to assert JSON data using nose2?

Tags: python, json, unit-testing, flask, nose2

I'm trying to test my API (written with Flask) using nose2. The response could look something like that:

```
{
  "finished": [
    {
      "id": 1, 
      "position": 1, 
      "time": "03:45.333"
    }, 
    {
      "id": 2, 
      "position": 2, 
      "time": "03:56.560"
    }
  ], 
  "not_finished": [
    {
      "id": 3, 
      "position": 3,
      "time": null
    }
  ]
}
```

For example I'd like to make sure that players 1 and 2 are in `finished` group, and player 3 is in `not_finished`. But in order to do so I need this data in a format that I can work with, and all nose2 gives me is long string.

Is there a way to retrieve the data in some friendly format with nose2?

Comment: If you `import json` you can do `json.loads(some_variable_pointing_to_your_string)` and you will get a python `dict` object to work with.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!